# Creating CV (html and pdf) with python

Tags: python, report

this is more a suggestion research than a proper question. Starting point are:

- data in a postgres database
- python solution needed

What am I looking for?

- fetching data from the postgres database within a python script
- python script must generate:

  1. html CV with custom CSS style sheet
  2. pdf CV, again with custom style
  3. pdf CV with EUROPASS style (https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/)

The ideal workflow is that, when adding a job/conference/something in the database, the script will update (deleting and creating again) all the CV type.

After many researches I found:

- ReportLab (https://www.reportlab.com/): it only produces pdf
- python with jinja template (only html)
- python flask (?)

I know that this is a super generic question, but I was wondering to some suggestion if someone faced similar problems.